# Using If, Then, Else on Condition in XML

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, if-statement

Can anyone help on how to process the information within Fields only when the `Condition` is `True` ?

I've tried For each and if then but I would like something more graceful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<Events>  
    <Event Id="1">
        <Condition>True</Condition>
        <Fields>
            <Parameter Name="thisOne" Value="1234" />
            <Parameter Name="notthisOne" Value="xyz" />
            <Parameter Name="thisoneagain" Value="5678" />
            <Parameter Name="notthisoneAgain" Value="abc" />
        </Fields>
    </Event>
    <Event Id="2">
        <Condition>False</Condition>
        <Fields>
            <Parameter Name="thisOne" Value="1234" />
            <Parameter Name="notthisOne" Value="xyz" />
            <Parameter Name="thisoneagain" Value="5678" />
            <Parameter Name="notthisoneAgain" Value="abc" />
        </Fields>
    </Event>
</Events>  
</root>
```

Comment: What vehicle are you using to parse your xml?  LINQ? XMLT? XPath?

Comment: LINQ at the minute but open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var paramSets = e.Descendants("Event")
                 .Where(ev => (string)ev.Element("Condition") == "True")
                 .Select(ev => ev.Descendants("Parameter")
                                 .Select(p => new
                                 {
                                     Name = (string)p.Attribute("Name"),
                                     Value = (string)p.Attribute("Value")
                                 }));
```

This will select a set of parameters for each `Event` element where `Condition` is `True`. In other words, the type of `paramSets` is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, where `T` is an anonymous type with a `Name` and `Value` property.

You can loop through it like this:

```
foreach (var event in paramSets)
{
    foreach (var parameter in event)
    {
        // Do something with the parameter
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle and JL. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where` Clause to restrict the set of data in LINQ to XML.

You can get the value of a particular element by drilling down into the element and calling `.Value`

This will load all the name and value for all the each parameter that is part of an Event that has a condition element with a value of True:

```vb
Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(str)

Dim parameters = From e In xdoc.Root.Elements("Events").Elements("Event")
                 From p In e.Elements("Fields").Elements("Parameter")
                 Where e.Element("Condition").Value = "True"
                 Select New With {
                         .Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
                         .Value = p.Attribute("Value").Value
                     }
```